# Does acrolein give positive iodoform test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, organic-oxidation

> Which of the following compound(s) give(s) a positive iodoform test?
>
> **A**. Acrolein
> **B**. Acetone
> **C**. Acetoacetic ester
> **D**. 2-Propanol

According to me, the answer should be options **B**, **C**, and **D** as **B** is a methyl ketone, **C** is a β-ketoester and **D** can be converted to methyl ketone by tautomerization.

But the answer in the key is given as **A**, **B**, **C**, and **D**. I cannot figure out why **A** is there. Is the key correct or does it need correction for **A**?

[image]

I thought of the above mechanism for reaching the answer. Is this reasoning alright? Please approve it, whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: Your reasoning "D can be converted to methyl ketone by tautomerization" is incorrect. It is an oxidation by the testing reagent $(\ce{I2/OH-})$, which converts 2-propanol to acetone.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me @MathewMahindaratne that really made me clear about secondary alcohols giving the IODOFORM test

Comment: Thank you @adselisk for presenting my question in a better way.